# restricting fields from elasticsearch query to be search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to know if I can exclude certain fields from search from Elasticsearch. To eloborate I want to ignore it from my search scope. It should not search that field when we specify but should be searchable on all the fields other then thats fields.

In the below data I want to achieve2 things:-

- I want to search for Product ABC in all other fields other then
  'Service_Sold' attribute.
- I want to restrict particular fields of some attributes to be **not
  searchable** like I want to restrict Elasticsearch to not search in this
  field 'Service_Sold.Type'

I came across excludes and whitelisting methods which is not feasible as we have lots of fields in index and would increase the complexity of the query.

Would appreciate any suggestions and help.

Note 7.10 version elastic-seach running queries on KIBANA. We can also upgrade our verison if required.

Here is the sample document.

```
{
        "_index" : "_dev",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "data-2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "datas",
          "id_number" : 736762732784934,
          "date" : "2011-01-26",
          "Service_Sold" : [
            {
              "Type" : "Type XYZ",
              "Product_Name" : "Product ABC"
            }
          ],
          "Product_Sold" : [
            {
              "Type" : "Type XYZ",
              "Product_Name" : "Product ABC"
            }
          ]
          ...
          50 other attributes
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use **"copy_to"**.
Just update your index mapping and create a field called "search_all", with a "text" mapping.
Then use "copy_to" on all the fields that you want to have searchable, and fire your queries on the copy_to field.
Example mapping:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Service_Sold": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Product_Sold": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "search_all" 
      },
      "Some_other_Field": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "search_all" 
      },
      "search_all": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the mapping above, **"Product_sold","Some other field"** will get copied to search_all. But "Service_Sold" will not be copied. When you search, simply do a "match" or "match_phrase" but only on the "search_all" field.

This way you can exclude without complicating your query.

As for the second part of restricting just to "Service Sold.type", you can just do a simple match query on that field. You don't need to do anything special There.

[Copy_To_Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html)

EDIT:
If you want to dynamically change the fields that you are querying, you can use "search_templates", where you can pass in the field name/names as a variable.

[Search Templates.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html)

Comment: Hey, @brugia Thanks for the reply, Actually our requirement can be changed at any time which means whatever field we don't want to be searchable now, later we can make it searchable and for that, we don't want to reindex data and change mapping again and again as we have a large amount of data. So that's why we need to index the whole data. for the second part, I have edited my post.

Comment: Answer edited, it is possible to do this only with search_templates.